# How to call JavaScript class's method from another method?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, ecmascript-6

I am using iOS's JavaScriptCore framework but I am having difficulty getting a JavaScript (es6) class to call another method.  Here is my playground code.

```
do {
    let j = JSContext()!

    j.evaluateScript("class Base123 { method1(arg1) { return this.method2(arg1) } method2(arg1) { return {\"asdf\":\"123\"} } }")
    j.evaluateScript("var b = new Base123(); var handler = b.method1")
    j.evaluateScript("handler(4)")?.toDictionary() //<-- expected ["asdf": "123"]
}
```

Essentially I am Creating a class called Base123 with two methods.  method1 calls method2.  However the call to method2 is undefined.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Reformatting the class definition to make it easier to read:

```
class Base123 { 
    method1(arg1) { 
        return this.method2(arg1) 
    } 
    method2(arg1) { 
        return {"asdf":"123"} 
    } 
}
```

Is there something wrong with this javascript definition?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I was able to solve it by wrapping the call with a closure.  `var handler = (arg1) => b.method1(arg1)`

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing `var handler = b.method1` with `var handler = b.method1.bind(b)`.